# Is there a function in python that can download Microsoft Forms excel sheet?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I created a Microsoft Form survey using google chrome, where I sent the link to different individuals to complete the survey, now I would like to see all the responses from individuals that have completed the survey. How can I download the Microsoft Form excel sheet directly from chrome using python?

Code:

```
   import selenium
   from selenium import webdriver

   driver = webdriver.Chrome()
   driver.get("Microsoft Form Link")
   button = driver.find_element_by_id('Open in Excel')
   button.click()
```

But i got this error:

```
WebDriverException: Message: 'chrome driver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see 
https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
```

Comment: do you have access to your azure tenancy ? if so try & leverage the Microsoft Graph API - further more it looks like you haven't downloaded the chrome driver and added it to your path `driver = webdriver.Chrome(path_to_driver)`

Comment: your error isn't about downloading the excel sheet, it's about getting selenium to work properly at all. You should ask a new question about that in my opinion

Answer (score 0):

You have to download the chromedriver that matches with your Chrome browser from here: https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

Then you have to add this:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'PATH TO THE FILE\chromedriver.exe')
```